# how to replace value in json with php

Tags: php

I don't really understand the php code, I've looked for several sources but still can't.
this is my line of code and what i want to change is the existing **UnitID** on **SMART ID** to **000000**.

```
{
  "idline":"27",
  "idlock":"33",
  "data":"[  
      {    
        "ID":"SMART",
        "Sort":"1",    
        "UnitID":"445678909"  
        
      },  
      {    
        "ID":"BOGLE",    
        "Sort":"1",    
        "UnitID":"57766446"  
        
      }
    ]"
}
```

Comment: deserialize, loop over `data`, search for `"SMART"`, replace the value inside `UnitID`, reserialize

Comment: do you have example code

Comment: I doubt in 30 seconds you searched anything

Comment: I've been about 5 hours to find the solution but still can't find a suitable one

Comment: Show us what you've tried and tell us what doesn't work

Comment: I forgot I deleted it. That's why I want to ask for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$json =
    '{
    "idline": "27",
    "idlock": "33",
    "data": "[
        {
            "ID": "SMART",
            "Sort": "1",
            "UnitID": "445678909"
        },
        {
            "ID": "BOGLE",
            "Sort": "1",
            "UnitID": "57766446"
        }
    ]"
}';
$json  = str_replace(["\"[", "]\""], ["[", "]"], $json);
$arr   = json_decode($json, true);
$index = array_search('SMART', array_column($arr['data'], 'ID'));
$arr['data'][$index]['UnitID'] = '00000000';
$json  = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$json  = str_replace(['[', ']'], ['"[', ']"'], $json);
```

// I think this is better for big data

```
$json = str_replace(["\"[", "]\""], ["[", "]"], $json);
$arr  = json_decode($json, true);
$data = [];
foreach ($arr['data'] as $datum) {
    $data[$datum["ID"]] = $datum;
}
if(isset($data['SMART'])){
    $data['SMART']['UnitID'] = '00000000';
}
$arr['data'] = array_values($data);
$json  = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$json  = str_replace(['[', ']'], ['"[', ']"'], $json);
```

Comment: there are quotes inside the data array. so still nothing happened..  "data":"[

Comment: This isn't a valid JSON, but anyway, I edited the answer and used str_replace.....